# Make Font Larger On iPad Than iPhone in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite Kit to add a bunch of labels; I want to add a bunch of text but I guess I have to do them as individual `SKLabelNode` because SpriteKit doesn't have a single, large text area.

I am adding a `SKLabelNode` with the `fontSize` property set to `32`, which looks fine on the iPhone 5 but it looks really small on the iPad Retina.

My questions is: How do I make `fontSize` property `32` for iPhone and something like `64` for iPad.

Snippet of my code for one label:

```
SKLabelNode *line1 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Kronoware"];
line1.text = @"FloppyPig.com";
line1.fontColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
line1.fontSize = 32;   // This is what I want to make dynamic for iPhone and iPad.
line1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame);
[self addChild:line1];
```

Comment: Just give a condition for iPhone and iPad and specify if your device is iPad then font size 64 else 32 for iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` to check what type of device it is and then set the `fontSize` accordingly. For example:

```
SKLabelNode *line1 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Kronoware"];
line1.text = @"FloppyPig.com";
line1.fontColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
line1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame);

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     line1.fontSize = 64; //iPad
}
else
{
     line1.fontSize = 32; //iPhone
}

[self addChild:line1];
```